# JMeter: How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error

Tags: jmeter, performance

Tool - JMeter, version 5.1.1

I am testing an application with API request and I am getting an error:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` for load test.

This issue occurs when I try to execute only load test with number of users simultaneously.
I have had a word with the Dev team and as per them there is no issue from server side configuration.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue. Appreciate quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Establishing an SSL session is a resource intensive process, you might want to check whether your server is overloaded, it might me the case it lacks resources like CPU, RAM, etc. when you put the load onto it hence it fails to respond to the handshake in a timely fashion.

You could consider using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to ensure that the server (and JMeter as well) have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, etc. cause it might cause the problem

If the server/JMeter is/are not overloaded but you still experience the issue you can temporary enable debugging of SSL events by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.debug=ssl
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up, once you restart JMeter and run your test you should see a lot of SSL-related information in the [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)).

More information: [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)